# What are the images of a point in a multi-layer mirror systems?

Tags: geometry

We all know that there are infinite images of a point which is located between two parallel mirrors. Also, the locations of the images can be easily obtained. Generally, how to locate the images of a point source if there are more than three (infinite and plane) interfaces ("mirrors")?

Comment: Mirrors perpendicular to a common (floor) plane, or intersecting one another? In 3D space or higher dimensions? All of them parallel, or if not, are the angles between them equal to $\pi$ divided by some integer? What kind of description do you expect for an infinite set of points? Are you looking for an algorithm to enumerate all of them exactly once? Do you know about Coxeter Groups? What kind of background do you have?

Comment: @MvG Well, in my case, the problem is considered in 2D or 3D, and all mirror are parallel. It may be regarded as sort of stratified medium. Moreover, the thickness of each layer (or the distance between two neighboring mirrors) could be arbitrary. As you pointed out, the images of a point source might be an infinite set of points or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Parallel mirrors make this essentially a one-dimensional problem, since for any point, all its mirror images will be on a line through that point and perpendicular to all the mirrors.

Two mirror reflections combine to a translation by a distance which is twice the distance between the mirrors. Conversely, the group of transformations generated by these two reflections is equal to the group of transformations generated by the translation and one of the reflections.

For more than two reflections, the most important distinction is whether or not the distances between the mirrors are [commensurable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commensurability_%28mathematics%29) or not. If they are, then you obtain the group generated by one reflection (choose any of the mirrors) and a translation by twice the greatest common divisor of all the distances between the mirrors. So there is an equivalent pair of mirrors which would yield the same group. If, on the other hand, the distances are not commensurable, then the orbit of any point under the group generated by the mirrors is everywhere dense, so you'd essentially be seeing a whole line, or at least a dense but countable subset thereof.

Comment: Thanks @MvG. Yes, it is essentially a one dimensional problem. What happens if the point source is located in the first or last (semi-infinite thickness) layer rather than in between mirrors? And the distance between the point and the first mirror is greater than the thickness of the layer (take two mirrors for instance), how to locate the images then? What's the situations for more than two mirrors in general? In addition, how about the images of a point in a cylindrical coaxial multilayer systems or spherical concentric multilayers?